# Insert to a table from another database AND the same database (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Maybe you guys can give me a hand; I have two databases and I need to insert data from the second database into the first one but I also need an Id from the first database. Both databases are on the same server.

The first database is `BiologiaBd` and contains the table `personal` with a column `Id` and a name called `nombre`.

The second database is called `Herpetologia` and contains a table called `CuadernoCampo`, this table has an id called `IdCC` and a name called `NomeColeCC`. This is the same name that the table `personal` in `BiologiaBd`

So, I have something like this

```
USE BiologiaBd
GO

INSERT INTO CuadernoCampo (codigoCuadernoCampo, idPersonal) 
    SELECT 
        IdCC, idPersonal 
    FROM 
        Herpetologia.dbo.CuadernosCampo, <--BiologiaBd
    WHERE
        idPersonal = (SELECT idPersonal 
                      FROM BiologiaBd 
                      WHERE nombre = (SELECT NomeColeCC 
                                      FROM Herpetologia.dbo.CuadernosCampo))
```

It won't work because I can't add the first database on the "from", some ideas?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: Please look here on how to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Oh, sorry is my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just if anyone wonders the answer was this

```
USE BiologiaBd
GO
INSERT INTO CuadernoCampo (codigoCuadernoCampo,idPersonal) 
SELECT db1.IdCC, db2.idPersonal FROM Herpetologia.dbo.CuadernosCampo db1
JOIN BiologiaBd.dbo.Personal db2 ON db1.NomeColeCC=db2.nombre
```

Thx again!

Answer (score 2):

You likely need a JOIN, as in:

```
INSERT INTO CuadernoCampo (codigoCuadernoCampo,idPersonal) 
  SELECT db1.IdCC, db2.idPersonal FROM CuadernosCampo db1
    JOIN BiologiaBd db2 ON db1.nombre=db2.NomeColeCC
```

Assuming that there is a record in BiologiaBd for each record in CuadernoCampo.

Comment: Thx, but what about the "from" do I just put both databases there?

Comment: Just the first database. The second database is specified after the JOIN - this is the one you were 'looking up' in your query.

Comment: but if i try USE BiologiaBd
GO
INSERT INTO CuadernoCampo (codigoCuadernoCampo,idPersonal) 
  SELECT db1.IdCC, db2.idPersonal FROM CuadernosCampo db1
    JOIN BiologiaBd db2 ON db1.nombre=db2.NomeColeCC
FROM Herpetologia.dbo.CuadernosCampo       I get a Syntax error near the word from

Comment: That  'FROM Herpetologia.dbo.CuadernosCampo' you have at the end, you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

[You should just be able to specify the database name](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180770%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) when referencing the table:

```
insert into CuadernoCampo (codigoCuadernoCampo,idPersonal) 
SELECT IdCC, idPersonal 
FROM BiologiaBd.dbo.CuadernosCampo, <--BiologiaBd
where idPersonal = (select idPersonal from BiologiaBd where nombre = (Select   
NomeColeCC from Herpetologia.dbo.CuadernosCampo))
```

Does this not work?

Comment: Sorry I tried to add code; that code does't work because the table cuadernosCampo is on The herpetologia database, I need to add 2 databases on the from like this FROM Herpetologia.dbo.CuadernosCampo, BiologiaBd but I get syntax error in the FROM